# How to prevent reordering of Cassandra Set when getting data with Java driver

Tags: cassandra, set, datastax-java-driver

[Retrieval using collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryCollections.html) describes collections order. In my case the feature of returning an ordered collection from the `set <text>` type is what I need. But collection deserilized to java `Set` and java `Set` does not provide any guarantee that the order of the elements will kept. Therefore, the query result may differ from the java object.

I try `getSet()` and it returns ordered collection. I don't undestand why. Perhaps this is due to deserialization of 'LinkedHashSet'?

How to guarantee getting a sorted collection with Java driver, as specified in the Cassandra documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Guaranteed by `SetCodec<T>`:

```
package com.datastax.driver.core;

public abstract class TypeCodec<T> {

...

  /**
   * This codec maps a CQL {@link DataType#set(DataType) set type} to a Java {@link Set}.
   * Implementation note: this codec returns mutable, non thread-safe {@link LinkedHashSet}
   * instances.
   */
  private static class SetCodec<T> extends AbstractCollectionCodec<T, Set<T>> {

    private SetCodec(TypeCodec<T> eltCodec) {
      super(DataType.set(eltCodec.cqlType), TypeTokens.setOf(eltCodec.getJavaType()), eltCodec);
    }

    @Override
    protected Set<T> newInstance(int size) {
      return new LinkedHashSet<T>(size);
    }
  }
```